# Pyscripter and printing line of CSV file

Tags: python, csv, text, printing, pyscripter

Here is my code:

```
 import csv,math
 StudentsTXT=open('students.txt')
 csv_students=csv.reader(StudentsTXT, delimiter=',')
 am =input('please search ip adress')
```

I also tried this code :

```
 import csv,math
 StudentsTXT=open('students.txt')
 csv_students=csv.reader(StudentsTXT, delimiter=',')
 print(csv_students['013'])
```

But this one comes up with error saying:object has no attribute'**getitem**'

How can I make one of these codes to print out line of my text file already translated into csv.

The Text file looks something like this

```
010,Jane,Jones,30/11/2001,32|Ban Road,H.Num:899 421 223,Female,11Ca,JJ@school.com
012,John,Johnson,23/09/2001,43|Can Street,H.Num:999 123 323,Male,11Ca,JoJo@school.com 
025,Jack,Jackson,29/02/2002,61|Cat grove,H.Num:998 434 656,Male,11Ca,JaJa@school.com
```

I want to be able to search for any of the names of any students and then print all information about them .

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i want to be able to search for any of the names of any students and then print all information about them and i forgot how to do it

Comment: A `csv.reader` is an iterator over the rows of the file, so `csv_students['013']` is just nonsense.`for row in csv_students: print row[:2]` will display the 2 first fields of each row.

Comment: If I try your Example I got: _**TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable**_. `csv_students` is a `Iterator` Object.

Comment: the thing is i want it to print things like for example:



     002,John,Smith,01/01/2001,1 example road,000 000 000,male,11ca,js@school.com 



instead of:



     001, john
     002,jane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**:  i want it to print things like for example:
>
> ```
> 002,John,Smith,01/01/2001,1 example road,000 000 000,male,11ca,js@school.com instead of: 001, john 002,jane
> ```

Change to `csv.DictReader`, for instance:

> **Note**: Assuming you have **NO** Headers in the CSV File!

```
with open('students.txt') as fh:
    # Define Header Fieldnames
    fieldnames = ['Name', 'SName', 'ID', 'Date', 'Address', 'Kontakt', 'F/M', 'Class', 'EMail']
    csv_students = csv.DictReader(fh, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    # Iterate csv_students
    for student in csv_students:
        # Create a List of Data Ordered using Fieldnames
        student_list = [student[f] for f in fieldnames]
        print('{}'.format(', '.join(student_list)))

        # Print only Part of the Fields
        print('{s[ID]}: {s[Name]} {s[Address]}'.format(s=student))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Jane, Jones, 010, 30/11/2001, 32|Ban Road, H.Num:899 421 223, Female, 11Ca, JJ@school.com
> 010: Jane 32|Ban Road
> John, Johnson, 012, 23/09/2001, 43|Can Street, H.Num:999 123 323, Male, 11Ca, JoJo@school.com
> 012: John 43|Can Street
> Jack, Jackson, 025, 29/02/2002, 61|Cat grove, H.Num:998 434 656, Male, 11Ca, JaJa@school.com
> 025: Jack 61|Cat grove
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***